# Force explicit zero values in summarise + n()

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse

R noob here, please bear with me!

I have a dataset in full tidy form that I'm trying to `summarise`. The records each have a `state`, `year`, and two different categories, which for now we'll say take on levels of `A, B, C` and `X, Y, Z`:

```
state    year    cat1    cat2
AK       2010    A       X
AK       2010    B       Z
AK       2010    A       Y
AK       2010    C       Z
...
```

(For scale, there are ~500k records)

For each state-year combination, I'm trying to get a cross-tab of how many records there are with each combination of `cat1` and `cat2` level. I can do this with `group_by` and `summarise`:

```
data %>%
    group_by(state, year, cat1, cat2) %>%
    summarise(count = n())
```

Which yields something like:

```
state    year    cat1    cat2    count
AK       2010    A       X       32
AK       2010    A       Y       501
AK       2010    A       Z       109
AK       2010    B       X       47
AK       2010    B       Y       670
AK       2010    B       Z       38
AK       2010    C       X       812
AK       2010    C       Y       17
AK       2010    C       Z       294
...
```

And so on for each state-year combo.

**BUT** the problem is that for some state-year combos, certain combinations of `cat1` and `cat2` don't exist, mostly b/c of small sample sizes. For instance:

```
state    year    cat1    cat2    count
RI       2010    A       X       10
RI       2010    A       Y       17
RI       2010    B       Y       4
RI       2010    C       X       32
RI       2010    C       Z       12
...
```

In these cases, I would like to force the result of `group_by` + `summarise` to show *all* nine possible `cat1` and `cat2` pairs for each state-year combination, filling in zero values if there are no records of that combination. So the example above should then be:

```
state    year    cat1    cat2    count
RI       2010    A       X       10
RI       2010    A       Y       17
RI       2010    A       Z       0
RI       2010    B       X       0
RI       2010    B       Y       4
RI       2010    B       Z       0
RI       2010    C       X       32
RI       2010    C       Y       0
RI       2010    C       Z       12
...
```

How do I force these explicit zero values for the missing combinations?
(I have looked some at `complete` but cannot figure out how to make it work here, if it's relevant.)

Comment: As a side note, if you're just counting you can use a shortcut: `data %>% count(state, year, cat1, cat2)` which allows you to replace the group_by and summarise calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with

- coercing the columns you're grouping by to factors
- setting `.drop = FALSE` in the `group_by` statement.

Example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  x = factor(letters[1:5]),
  y = factor(c("x", "x", "y", "y", "z")),
  z = runif(length(x))
)

df %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  summarize(z = mean(z), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   x     y          z
#>   <fct> <fct>  <dbl>
#> 1 a     x     0.0468
#> 2 b     x     0.392 
#> 3 c     y     0.0914
#> 4 d     y     0.793 
#> 5 e     z     0.741

df %>% 
  group_by(x, y, .drop = FALSE) %>%  # attn
  summarize(z = mean(z), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 15 × 3
#>    x     y            z
#>    <fct> <fct>    <dbl>
#>  1 a     x       0.0468
#>  2 a     y     NaN     
#>  3 a     z     NaN     
#>  4 b     x       0.392 
#>  5 b     y     NaN     
#>  6 b     z     NaN     
#>  7 c     x     NaN     
#>  8 c     y       0.0914
#>  9 c     z     NaN     
#> 10 d     x     NaN     
#> 11 d     y       0.793 
#> 12 d     z     NaN     
#> 13 e     x     NaN     
#> 14 e     y     NaN     
#> 15 e     z       0.741
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to coerce to a factor, you can use `complete`

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  count(state, year, cat1, cat2) %>%
  complete(expand(., cat1, cat2), fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  fill(state, year) %>%
  select(state, year, cat1, cat2, n)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>   state  year cat1  cat2      n
#>   <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1 AK     2010 A     X         1
#> 2 AK     2010 A     Y         1
#> 3 AK     2010 A     Z         0
#> 4 AK     2010 B     X         0
#> 5 AK     2010 B     Y         0
#> 6 AK     2010 B     Z         1
#> 7 AK     2010 C     X         0
#> 8 AK     2010 C     Y         0
#> 9 AK     2010 C     Z         1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data taken from question**

```r
data <- structure(list(state = c("AK", "AK", "AK", "AK"), year = c(2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L), cat1 = c("A", "B", "A", "C"), cat2 = c("X", 
"Z", "Y", "Z")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```